# Este script me aparece en la ventana automático la acción del botón sin haberlo clickeado

Tags: python, tkinter, botón, ventana, ping

script para hacer ping a un servidor mediante una interfaz gráfica con tkinter pero aparece el resultado en la ventana sin haber clickeado el botón ping, o sea el botón no está llamando a la función ping, no sé xq pasa esto soy nueva programando en python

```
import platform 
import subprocess
import os
import time
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('PING')
window.geometry('600x400')



label_dos = tk.Label()
label_dos.grid(row=1,column=4)

def ping(ip):
 parametro = '-n' if 
 platform.system().lower() 
 =='windows' else '-c'  
 comando = 
 ['ping',parametro,'1',ip] 
 output=subprocess.getoutput(
 comando)
 label_uno.config(text="Pingint 
 to " + ip + "  ...")
 label_dos.config(text=output)   

def clear():
 label_uno.config(text="")
 label_dos.config(text="")

ping=Button(texto="ping", 
command=ping('192.168.0.100'))
ping.grid(row=0, columna=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

El [`kwarg`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) `command` recibe el nombre de función **sin paréntesis** para ejecutarse al presionar el botón en cuestión, si se pasan argumentos la función se ejecutará sin necesidad de haber presionado el botón.

**Entonces, como puede pasarle argumentos a función en `command`?**

En solución a esto se pueden hacer uso de la funciones anónimas, [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions). Para tu caso, puedes asignarle a `command` una `lambda` que retorne la función en cuestión. Adjunto un ejemplo:

```
Button(text = "ping", command = lambda: ping('192.168.0.100'))
```

Algo que se debe aclarar son las limitaciones de las funciones anonimas, o bien `lambda`. Estas pueden recibir cualquier cantidad de parámetros (de 0 hasta 100), pero solo pueden retornar un **único valor**.

**Una observación muy importante**

En Python la buena indentación y espaciado son **obligatorios**. En tu código hay fragmentos como este:

```
def ping(ip):
 parametro = '-n' if 
 platform.system().lower() 
 =='windows' else '-c'  
 comando = 
 ['ping',parametro,'1',ip] 
 output=subprocess.getoutput(
 comando)
 label_uno.config(text="Pingint 
 to " + ip + "  ...")
 label_dos.config(text=output)
```

Donde no solo se rompen las cadena de manera inadecuada, si no también no se usan los cuatro espacios de indentación. Hay que entender que en Python a diferencia de otros lenguajes de programación no hay caracteres que definen el final de una sentencia/expresión. [Estilo de código recomendado](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#intermezzo-coding-style).

Manera adecuada de escribir la función:

```
def ping(ip):
    parametro = '-n' if platform.system().lower() =='windows' else '-c'  
    comando = ['ping',parametro,'1',ip] 
    output = subprocess.getoutput(comando)
    label_uno.config(text = f"Pingint to {ip} ...")
    label_dos.config(text = output)
```

**Nota:** En este fragmento se cambia la concatenación con `+` por la de `f"{}"`, es más fácil de leer de esta manera.

Finalmente, te adjunto un código un poco más ordenado y con la implementación de la función anónima:

```
import platform 
import subprocess
import os
import time
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('PING')
window.geometry('600x400')

label_dos = tk.Label()
label_dos.grid(row = 1,column = 4)


def ping(ip):
    parametro = '-n' if platform.system().lower() =='windows' else '-c'  
    comando = ['ping',parametro,'1',ip] 
    output = subprocess.getoutput(comando)
    label_uno.config(text = f"Pingint to {ip} ...")
    label_dos.config(text = output)   


def clear():
    label_uno.config(text = "")
    label_dos.config(text = "")


#Se cambia el nombre del botón, ya que existía una función con el mismo nombre
pingbutton = Button(text = "ping", command = lambda: ping('192.168.0.100'))
pingbutton.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

window.mainloop()
```

Espero te haya servido, saludos!

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda, me sirvió de mucho!! Saludos.

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y me funcionó perfecto, realmente no había entendido el uso de las funciones anónimas así que muchas gracias por tu explicación.